# how does MDCTabBar. setSelectedItem work?

Tags: swift, material-components-ios

I'm using a `UIViewController` with

- MDCAppBarViewController
- MDCTabBar
- UICollectionView

The property `collectionView.isPagingEnabled` is `true` so I can use a "cell" for every child-ViewController.

The UI-update for switching the tab via "touch on the tab" works fine. But now I want to switch the tab with a swipe-left/right.

My problem is that the given `setSelectedItem`-method doesn't do anything on UI-side.

Comment: How you are calling `setSelectedItem`?

Comment: `tabBar.setSelectedItem(tabBar.items[currTabBarIndex], animated: true)`

Comment: I think you also have to use selectedItemTintColor & selectedItemTitleColor appropriately for it to be seen in ui.

Comment: I added `selectedItemTintColor ` but unfortunately the UI doesn't change